# How to display Arabic text to browser from database?

Tags: jquery-mobile, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to display Arabic text to my website from the database. But it will display **question mark "????"** . I connect it from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Do you see the question marks in phpMyAdmin or in your website?

Comment: @MarcDelisle in phpMyAdmin, the arabic text appear as usual. but in my website, it will display question mark (?).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your text to UTF format like this:

```
&#1575;&#1587;&#1605; &#1575;&#1604;&#1605;&#1587;&#1578;&#1582;&#1583;&#1605;
```

Result: اسم المستخدم

Comment: & # 1575 ; & # 1587 ; & # 1605;